# How to detect a url/image/youtube link and concat a tag around it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure how to do this.
Anyway to detect a url as content, and, then concat a tag around it?

I want this to be done in Javascript. Outputted in HTML.

Let's say I have a string with regular text, as well as a url in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

- http://benalman.com/code/javascript/ba-linkify.js

would do the job once you've identified your links. To do that you have to restrict the format of links, for example by requiring that they include the `http://` (or `https://` etc.). If you're only looking for well-formed links, you can search for strings beginning with `http://` etc. and ending before the first non-URL character:

- http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy

using regexp character classes:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

Comment: yea, but, how do I detect the specific part of the string that is a url?